# Taiko UI automation angular - Unable to use fileField to upload a csv file

Tags: node.js, csv, angular-ui-router, ui-automation, browser-automation

Experimenting with [Taiko](https://taiko.dev/) for UI automation. Trying to upload a csv file but giving the id of the csv file selector is not working. A red rectangle outline blinks on top of the file upload link file firing {attach("/Users/username/Downloads/report.csv",$('*[id="some"]'))} but shows following error message in console.

`` Error: Node is not a file input element, run `.trace` for more info. ``

HTML

[image]

I've tried following fieldfield examples from https://docs.taiko.dev/#filefield

```
attach('report.csv', to(fileField('Upload CSV file (Optional)')))
fileField('Upload CSV file (Optional)').exists()
fileField({'id':'event-csv-upload'}).exists()
fileField({id:'event-csv-upload'},below('Upload CSV file (Optional)')).exists()
fileField(below('Upload CSV file (Optional)')).exists()
```

none of this works and finally tried following

```
attach("/Users/username/Downloads/report.csv",$('*[id="event-csv-upload"]'))
and
attach("/Users/username/Downloads/report.csv",fileField({id:'event-csv-upload'}))

source:https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/issues/309
```

Still not able to upload file using Taiko.

Why this file upload element is difficult to locate in angular code?

Is it too early to try Taiko now for angular web projects?

Do you recommend any other UI automation framework that work well with any angular versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attach` expects a File input field as a selector to perform action on, in your case that element seems to be a hidden element linked to a button, attaching to that hidden element should work.
Try,

```
await attach("/Users/username/Downloads/report.csv",fileField({id:'eventCSVFileInput'},{ selectHiddenElements: true }))
```

Comment: Tried your line of code getting this concat error now.

`[FAIL] Error: File field[@id = concat('eventCSVFileInput', "")] and [object Object] not found`

Comment: Seems you are using a different selector, `fileField({id:'eventCSVFileInput'},{ selectHiddenElements: true })` this uses only id.. make sure you are on latest version of taiko

Comment: Was using 1.0.0 now Updated to taiko 1.0.13,Chromium:85.0.4168.0. Tried following
`attach("/Users/username/Downloads/report.csv",fileField({id:'eventCSVFileInput'},{ selectHiddenElements: true })`

Error seems to different now

`Thrown:
{ [SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," (2:1)
] loc: Position { line: 2, column: 1 }, pos: 137 }
...
Thrown:
{ [SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," (3:1)
] loc: Position { line: 3, column: 1 }, pos: 139 }
...`

Comment: Tried this, for some reason id is not detected

`fileField({'id':'csvFileInput'}).exists()
false [PASS] Does not exists`

Comment: Error with attach seems to be happening because of missing `)` at the end,  
```await attach("/Users/username/Downloads/report.csv",fileField({id:'eventCSVFileInput'},{ selectHiddenElements: true }))```

Comment: `fileField({'id':'csvFileInput'}).exists()`  if this is an hidden element do specify `{selectHiddenElements: true}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
await attach("/Users/username/Downloads/report.csv",fileField({id:'eventCSVFileInput'},{force:true}))
```